# How Insert string in a specified position of a JSON file using TStringList?

Tags: json, delphi

Is possible insert a string in a determinated position inside of a json file using `TStringList`?

I made a code that is able to search a substring with success, but only if file not contains "{}".

For example:

content of file: `"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true,`

but if content of file is: `{"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true,}`

`TStringList.IndexOf` fails.

Have some solution to it?

My actual code is:

```
uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SHFolder,
  SysUtils;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(folder: integer): string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
var
  path: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, folder, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @path[0])) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingBackslash(path)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure Modify_Json_File;
var
  SpecialFolder: Integer;
  SL: TStringList;
  InsTextPos: Integer;
  FileChrome: String;
begin
  SpecialFolder := CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA;
  FileChrome := GetSpecialFolderPath(SpecialFolder);
  FileChrome := FileChrome + 'Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State';
  if FileExists(FileChrome) then
  begin
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.LoadFromFile(FileChrome);
      InsTextPos := SL.IndexOf('"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true,');
      if InsTextPos > 0 then
      begin
        SL.Insert(InsTextPos, '"hardware_acceleration_mode":{"enabled":false}');
        SL.SaveToFile(FileChrome);
      end;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, use a JSON parser.

Comment: `"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true` and `{"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true}` are both valid JSON, but they have very different meanings (the first is a single string, the second is an object containing a string). You really do need to use an actual JSON parser to handle this situation. `TStringList` is not a good choice to use, especially since JSON is not even required to have line breaks in it

Comment: I want know if is possible use only `TStringList`,  without Json classes.

Comment: Is it *possible*? Yes, of course, anything is *possible*.  But, is it *advisable*? No. Parsing JSON is not trivial, `TStringList.IndexOf()` is not up to the task. Mainly because it is looking for an exact match, which you don't have. So, at the very least, you would have to manually loop through the JSON line-by-line (assuming it even has lines) searching each one for your substring

Comment: Ok, in this case **Local State** file of Google Chrome not have line breaks. But, in any case, could you give a example of how make this task using only `TStringList`?

Comment: I did in my answer

Comment: Use the right tool for the job, #dv

Comment: @David, domestic violence? I would prefer that parser :) [I guess it's voting related]

Comment: @Victoria DownVote, not allowed, or discouraged, to write -1  Even the string list is better than domestic violence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not advisable to use `TStringList` to process JSON in this manner.  You really should use an actual JSON parser.  [Embarcadero provides one in modern Delphi versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Json), and there are plenty of 3rd party ones available, too.

For example:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Classes,
  Winapi.SHFolder,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.IOUtils,
  System.JSON;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(folder: integer): string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
var
  path: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, folder, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @path[0])) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingBackslash(path)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure Modify_Json_File;
var
  FileChrome: String;
  Obj: TJSONObject;
  Pair: TJSONPair;
  OldString: TJSONString;
  OldValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  FileChrome := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA) + 'Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State';
  if FileExists(FileChrome) then
  begin
    Obj := TJSONObject.ParseJsonValue(TFile.ReadAllText(FileChrome), True) as TJSONObject;
    if Obj <> nil then
    try
      Pair := Obj.Get('hardware_acceleration_mode_previous');
      if Pair <> nil then
      begin
        OldString := Pair.JsonString;
        Pair.JsonString := TJSONString.Create('hardware_acceleration_mode');
        OldString.Free;

        OldValue := Pair.JsonValue;
        Pair.JsonValue := TJSONObject.Create;
        try
          TJSONObject(Pair.JsonValue).AddPair('enabled', TJSONBool.Create(false));
        finally
          OldValue.Free;
        end;

        TFile.WriteAllText(FileChrome, Obj.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
      end; 
    finally
      Obj.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In any case, if you must use a `TStringList`, you can't use `IndexOf()`, at least.  It is searching for an *exact whole-line match*, which you clearly don't have when your code fails.  So, you need to loop through the JSON content line-by-line (assuming it even has any lines - JSON does not require line breaks!), searching each one for the substring you are interested in, eg:

```
uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SHFolder,
  SysUtils;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(folder: integer): string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
var
  path: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, folder, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @path[0])) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingBackslash(path)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure Modify_Json_File;
const
  SearchText = '"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous":true,';
  ReplaceText = '"hardware_acceleration_mode":{"enabled":false},';
var
  SL: TStringList;
  I, InsTextPos: Integer;
  FileChrome, S: String;
begin
  FileChrome := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA) + 'Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State';
  if FileExists(FileChrome) then
  begin
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.LoadFromFile(FileChrome);
      for I := 0 to SL.Count-1 do
      begin
        S := SL[I];
        InsTextPos := Pos(SearchText, S);
        if InsTextPos > 0 then
        begin
          Delete(S, InsTextPos, Length(SearchText));
          Insert(ReplaceText, S, InsTextPos);
          SL[I] := S;
          SL.SaveToFile(FileChrome);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```